# Problems install/running meteor-angular

Tags: linux, angularjs, ubuntu, meteor

So bear in mind, I am new to meteor and my linux experience is definately not something to brag about.

I've setup an ubuntu environment using virtualbox and want to use that environment to write some meteor-angular apps. I had meteor running for a split second, but the second time I launched it, it stopped working.

I googled quite a bit, but it isn't the easier query to google and I tried reinstalling meteor several times.

```
pwnball@Pwnballer:~/development$ meteor create financialize
financialize: created.                        

To run your new app:                          
cd financialize                             
meteor                                      
pwnball@Pwnballer:~/development$ cd financialize/
pwnball@Pwnballer:~/development/financialize$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/development/financialize ]]]]]        

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

/home/pwnball/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.43.pv9wg1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parse (native)
at readSessionData (/home/pwnball/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.43.pv9wg1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth.js:134:15)
at Object.exports.getSessionId (/home/pwnball/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.43.pv9wg1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth.js:845:32)
at /home/pwnball/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.43.pv9wg1++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/stats.js:64:23
```

This is the result when I am trying to run my fresh app. Any clues or maybe pointers to help me win this fight? :)

Answer (score 2):

Meteor reset did not help, reinstalling meteor did not help.. however:

```
rm ~/.meteorsession
```

That did the trick! Funny how sometimes you're digging into a problem for hours and then all of the sudden it's fixed by something that simple :)